# In a Visual Studio pre-build event how do I execute an exe in the context of its own folder instead of the bin folder?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process, build-automation

I have a pre-build event defined like this:

```
$(ProjectDir)PreBuild\runthis.exe
```

When the runthis.exe executes, it runs in the context of the bin folder of my project instead of the PreBuild folder where it lives. How can I make the build event execute runthis.exe in the context of the PreBuild folder instead of the bin folder?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `cd $(ProjectDir)PreBuild` first to switch to that folder.