# How to call cmd application from prebuild process of another application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a console application `'DbCreate'` which create **.mdf** file. And I have another application which uses that **.mdf** file.
How can I call pre-buld action of the second application, which will first call DbCreate application?
Thanks for help

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767157/in-a-visual-studio-pre-build-event-how-do-i-execute-an-exe-in-the-context-of-its

Comment: How will you ensure that the first application has finished creating .mdf file before your application launches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is theoretically possible (reparse point) it would be very hard. A "prebuilt" application does what it is programmed to do, which also implies that it does *not* do what it's *not* programmed to do. If you want to change the behavior of the second program, you'll most likely need to alter that second program.

If the second program offers configuration options for this feature, then it's possible but it wouldn't be a programming question anymore.